# Conservative force for impulse analogous to conservative force for work done?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservative-field

As force $F(x)$ can be conservative regarding work done between two points in space, can force $F(t)$ be conservative regarding impulse between two points in time?

Comment: Thanks. So, that's why law of conservation of momentum isn't generalized for the cases where forces are present?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you define the new concept "conservative", by saying a force $F(t)$ is "conservative" if its impulse depends only on the initial and final instants of time, i.e.
$$\int_{t_a}^{t_b}F(t)dt=\phi(t_a,t_b)\Leftrightarrow \mbox{$F(t)$ is "conservative"},$$
then it would be useless. Every force would be "conservative" since time is a one parameter space. There is no different paths across time.

Something similar occurs with the usual concept of conservative forces in one dimensional spaces. Every force field in one dimension that depends only on the spatial coordinate is conservative.

Comment: If every force would be conservative for time parameter, can't we generalize the momentum conservation law for the cases where these kinds of forces are present.                 P(t') + Potential Impulse(t')=P(t) + Potential Impulse(t)

Comment: @Nabin This new concept you invented has nothing to do with momentum conservation. "Conservative" would be a bad term to use. Momentum is conserved if it is constant in time, that is $0=dp=Fdt$. The force should be zero in order to conserve momentum.

Comment: Is frictional force in 1-D conservative? In moving an object between two points, if i go from the initial point, past the final point and again return to it, for this path, won't the work be different than just moving straight from initial to the final point?

Comment: @Nabin The work would be different so the force is not conservative. But notice that I said 1-D forces depending only on the spatial coordinate is conservative. If it depends either on the velocity or explicitly on time then it is no longer conservative.